# ASP.NET Core Image Resize

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, image-resizing, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to resize imagine with `System.Drawing` but im taking that file as `IFormFile` and when i use the `System.Drawing` its just keep warning me to about that : `cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'` . I need to resize those photos and save them as `IFormFile` but i dont know how to do that.

```cs
public Task<IFormFile> ResizeImagine300x300(IFormFile file)
{
    Image image = Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream(), true, true);
    var newImage = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
    };
    return newImage;//the point where i get the error
}
```

Is it possible to do it in my way?

If its not possible, then which way i should follow?

**Thanks for any suggestion**

Edit: I wanna return as a `IFormFile` because i have a method which is uploading those files to my database. here is my method :

```cs
public async Task<FileRepo> FileUploadToDatabase(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        _fileRepo = new FileRepo
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            FileExtension = fileExtension,
            FileType = file.ContentType,
            CreatedDate= DateTime.Now
        };
        using (var dataStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(dataStream);
            _fileRepo.FileData = dataStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    return _fileRepo;
}
```

After that I'm uploading that `_fileRepo` variable to my database like that :

```
 var File = _fileUploader.FileUploadToDatabase(files);
 var FileResult = File.Result;
 FileResult.ProductID = ProductID;
 _unitOfWorkFR.RepositoryFileRepo.Create(FileResult);
```

Comment: Why do you need to return `IFormFile` from this method? Makes no sense to me. Just return a `Stream` and process it outside

Comment: because i have a method which is only  accept ```IFormFile``` stream and save them to database as binary.

Comment: Please post that method's code

Comment: i have edited my question for u @Alexander